# How to restore menu in LXTerminal?

Tags: lxterminal

I have turned off the menu in LXTerminal to save screen space. How do I bring it back?

I have tried hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and such, but the menu does not show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LXTerminal version 0.3.1 open,

- Right-click anywhere in the terminal's window (but not in the title bar, scrollbar, etc). A context menu appears.
- Click on *Preferences > Display* and uncheck *Hide menu bar*.

[image: LXTerminal right-click menu]

[image: Toggle hide menu bar]

Answer (score 0):

Try the button combination of Alt+F

Of course thinking about it now, could you just try opening up a new terminal window? I think by default it will automatically bring up the menu bar unless you configured it not to.

You could also try right clicking on the Terminal in the OS program group and click on Preferences and then creating a hot-key combination to prevent this issue in the future.